# jQuery File Upload - blueimp server issue

Tags: php, jquery-ui, file-upload, blueimp

I've set up the jQuery File Upload - blueimp on my local server and everything works great!

I uploaded the script onto my server and when I upload images I recieve this error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

my files are uploaded, both the originals and the thumbnails, but for some reason it wont show the files that are uploaded.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Do you have code examples? Configuration information? Anything to help us help you?  It is obviously a syntax issue with code somewhere but, since you have not provided any source, I can't help you target how to fix it.

Comment: Which part of the code?

Comment: Again, there is a syntax issue here somewhere but without more details there is little anyone can do to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem. I had to downgrade my php to 5.3 :) thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the original ui php upload handler code? You may be experiencing a json response issue so it will be good to analyze post/get using firebug or chrome inspect element. Be sure not to echo/print anything in your PHP uploader since this could cause that error based on my experience.

Comment: I changed the code so that it pulls images from my database. That's about it, i don't think its the uploader because it uploads everything properly. it just doesn't show the thumbnails.

Comment: If you changed the code, odds are that is where your problem lies if that is the variance between your local (where it works) and the server (where it doesn't).  Process of elimination.